Adding an address for user during front-end registration
Is there any way to add an address for a prospective user during front-end registration on Craft 5?
I'm trying to set up front-end registration on a Craft 5 site. The ideal process is that a prospective user will fill in a front-end registration form as described in the official knowledge base (https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/front-end-user-accounts) which will create a deactivated user. That prospective user's details will then be manually checked by an admin prior to being sent an activation email.
The problem lies in collecting an address from the prospective user. As far as I can tell, users can only create/edit their own addresses after they are activated and logged in. In my case a 2-step process where the address is added later is not acceptable as the address needs to be manually checked before the user is activated.
Does anyone have a solution for this?
Note: I'm aware that a similar question was asked back in 2020 (Add billing address to user on registration) but there was no answer regards achieving this without a 2 step flow.

Not sure if it helps at all, but here's how I did it in Craft 4 (sorry still not had to upgrade that one to 5 yet, so not sure if there's a better or more native way now) https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/41876/271

Looks very promising, thanks! I'll try it out on Craft 5 and report back.
